# Is it possible to enable gzip compression in nuxt static?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

i've tried to use this config to my httacces file, but it doesnt work. the assets still has no encode

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*\.(css|html|js)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -s
RewriteRule ^(.+) $1.gz Apache for recompressing the files
RewriteRule "\.css\.gz$" "-" [T=text/css,E=no-brotli,E=no-gzip]
RewriteRule "\.html\.gz$" "-" [T=text/html,E=no-brotli,E=no-gzip]
RewriteRule "\.js\.gz$" "-" [T=application/javascript,E=no-brotli,E=no-gzip]
<FilesMatch "\.(css|html|js)\.br$">
     RemoveLanguage .br
     Header set Content-Encoding br
     Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(css|html|js)\.gz$">
     Header set Content-Encoding gzip
     Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
</FilesMatch>
```